# Magento 2 check if Page is used on more than one website

Tags: magento2, multistore, page

I'm trying to find if a page is used on more than one website on a multi-website Magento installation.

I have sucessfully return data of the page, but PageInterface has nothing like getStores() or getWebsites().

Here is my code:

```
public function getPageData($identifier){
        $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('identifier', $identifier,'eq')->create();
        $pages = $this->_pageRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        return $pages;
    }
```

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: You can add store id in to the `searchCriteria` then `count` the result to verify it exists

Comment: how would that be? have identifier of page and also store id?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.

In `Magento\Cms\Model\Page;`There is a method called `getStores()`

So this is how I made it work:

```
use Magento\Cms\Model\Page;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Page;

class Main extends Template
{
    protected $_page;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        Page $page,

    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->_page = $page;
        
    }

    public function getStores(){
        $stores = $this->_page->getStores();
        return $stores;
    }

}
```